# PL/SQL setting a conditional variable based on environment

Tags: oracle, plsql

In my PL/SQL function I need to return a different variable based on environment it is running in (Development, QA, or Production). What is the best way to do that without having different code in each environment?

I was thinking using CASE statement:

```
CASE l_server
   WHEN 'DEV' THEN 'development'
   WHEN 'QA' THEN 'test'
   WHEN 'PROD' THEN 'production'
   ELSE 'unknown'
END;
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: that's as good as anything else.   how does l_server get assigned its values?

Comment: via global_name

Comment: Why not put that in a  table in each environment and use a function to get the production status of the environment you're on ?

Comment: You can store the value of the variable in some parameter table or use conditional compilation.

Answer (score 0):

If the logic for testing `global_name` is consistent across environments (it should be if you have a naming convention for DB instances), then why not create a common function in the app schema across all instances?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_env RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    v_env VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE global_name
        WHEN 'DEV' THEN 'development'
        WHEN 'QA' THEN 'test'
        WHEN 'PROD' THEN 'production'
        ELSE 'unknown' END
    INTO v_env
    FROM global_name;
    RETURN v_env;
END get_env;
```

The value in a table approach works too but relies on someone or something ensuring the table values are correct for each instance, whereas directly querying `global_name` is a bit more robust as it only relies on the DB having the right name when it gets created.